# How to logout programmatically from magnolia cms

Tags: java, jax-rs, magnolia

I'd like to create custom REST for logging out users. I created jax-rs based endpoint definition with one method `/logout`:

```
@Path("/test")
public class MyEndpoint<D extends EndpointDefinition>  extends AbstractEndpoint<D> {

    @Path("/logout")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void logout() {
        //how to logout user here?
    }
}
```

What code should I put in place of `//how to logout user here?` to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created working solution based on `info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter`

```
@Path("/logout")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void logout(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    info.magnolia.context.Context ctx = MgnlContext.getInstance();
    if (ctx instanceof UserContext) {
        AuditLoggingUtil.log((UserContext) ctx);
        ((UserContext) ctx).logout();
    }

    if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the following component and trigger logout from it.

```
info.magnolia.context.UserContext
```